# Referring to the lightness/darkness of colors

Tags: terminology, colors

Presently I have 3 different colors.  I am referring to them as:

- light (could be sky blue or pink)
- middle (could be blue or red)
- dark (could be navy or crimson)

Is there a better way to describe the lightness darkness of the colors?

If I had four or five different darknesses that I waned to describe what would be the best way to refer to them?  The best I have come up with would be something like:

- very light
- light
- middle
- dark
- very dark

Comment: Did you check a thesaurus for synonyms of "light", "dark", and "medium"?

Comment: @MattGutting - For 'dark', the thesaurus returns things like: black, darkened, dim, shadowy, obscure, unlit.  If I told you, I had a dark color and a dim color which would you say was closer to black (ie darker).

Comment: The usual term is mid-blue not middle blue.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context, but in photography the tones are sometimes called:

- White
- Highlight
- Midtone
- Shadow
- Black